# Retrieve Data from DynamoDB if complete sort key not known

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to DyanmoDB. I am creating partition key and sort key when pushing data into DynamoDb but when i want to retrieve the data i have the partition key but not the complete sort key. I know the beginning of the sort key but not the complete key.

```
table.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder().queryConditional(QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue("KEY#" + id).build())).build())
```

Below are the tables partition and sort key:

```
private static final String TEMPLATE = "%s#%s";    
@DynamoDbPartitionKey
      @Override
      public String getPk() {
        return String.format(TEMPLATE, "KEY", getId());
      }
    
      @DynamoDbSortKey
      @Override
      public String getSk() {
        return String.format(TEMPLATE, "KEY_SORT", getName());
      }
```

I used what i provided above but its showing this error:
The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: response id)
After looking into the issue i found out that key should be the combination of partition and sort key. But the issue is i don't know the complete sort key for the second request.

Comment: Can you first state what is your tables partition and sort key. Also share the values you have to make the request. I know what you need to do but I need more info to explain it more clearly to you.

Comment: I edited the question and provided the table details. Can you please help now?

Comment: my answer below should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`QueryConditional`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/QueryConditional.html) with [`sortBeginsWith()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/model/QueryConditional.html#sortBeginsWith(software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key)):

For example, imagine you have the following information

partition key `pk` = `"key#23456"`

sort key `sk` begins with `"abcd"`

you are unsure of the remainder of the sort key:

```
        QueryConditional condition = QueryConditional.sortBeginsWith(
                Key.builder()
                        .partitionValue("key#23456")
                        .sortValue("abcd")
                        .build()
        );

        QueryEnhancedRequest request = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .queryConditional(condition)
                .build();


        table.query(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only know the beginning of the sort key, you can use `BEGINS_WITH` query.

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name TABLE \
    --key-condition-expression "Id = :id and begins_with(Key, :key)" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":id":{"S":"1"}, ":key":{"S":"KEY-BEGINNING"}}'
```

You need to provide the primary key and the beginning of the sort key for this query.

See [Key condition expressions for query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)